delete the dummy of 0s, if there is dummy of 1s. But keep 0s if there is no dummy of 1s, for two columns
the dataset like this:
a  b  c d
a1 b1 1 0 
a1 b1 0 1
a1 b2 0 1
a1 b2 1 0

a2 b3 1 0 
a2 b3 1 0
a2 b4 0 0

if a1&b1 as a pair, have the dummy of 1 and 0 for column c, and 0 and 1 for column d. I want to have  the maximum dummy for each pair in each column.
output should be:
a  b  c d
a1 b1 1 1
a1 b2 1 1
a2 b3 1 0
a2 b4 0 0

I tried the function "slice_max(c, by (c(a,b))", but it can only do one column each time, if I use it for column c first, for a1&b1 pair, column 2&3 will be deleted and d will be 0 only.

This is a good case for summarize() from the dplyr package.
This is taking each pair of a and b, described in the .by argument, and finding the max value of c and the max value of d.
data <- tibble::tibble(
    a = c("a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a2"),
    b = c("b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b3", "b4"),
    c = c(   1,    0,    0,    1,    1,    1,    0),
    d = c(   0,    1,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0)
)

data
#> # A tibble: 7 × 4
#>   a     b         c     d
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a1    b1        1     0
#> 2 a1    b1        0     1
#> 3 a1    b2        0     1
#> 4 a1    b2        1     0
#> 5 a2    b3        1     0
#> 6 a2    b3        1     0
#> 7 a2    b4        0     0


data |> dplyr::summarize(
    c = max(c),
    d = max(d),
    .by = c(a, b)
)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   a     b         c     d
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a1    b1        1     1
#> 2 a1    b2        1     1
#> 3 a2    b3        1     0
#> 4 a2    b4        0     0

